# Add incrementing number to JSON object String to make them unique

Tags: javascript, regex, json, string, object

I have a JSON object that is being passed to me as a String, but the Object in its String form contains duplicate properties. I need to temporarily add incrementing numbers to the Properties in order to avoid the problem of duplicate JSON properties. Once I am done editing the Object, I will JSON.Stringify the object back to a String and remove the numbers.

Here is the String I am passed:

```
{
    "View":{
        "Image":{
            "BackgroundImage":"Image.png",
             "Position":[0,0],
             "Width":320,
             "Height":480
        },
        "Button":{
            "BackgroundImage":"ButtonTop.png",
             "Position":[61,83],
             "Width":217,
             "Height":58
        },
        "Button":{
            "BackgroundImage":"ButtonBottom.png",
             "Position":[61,214],
             "Width":205,
             "Height":73
        },
        "TextField":{
            "BackgroundImage":"TextFieldLogin.png",
             "Position":[102,336],
             "Width":189,
             "Height":31
        },
        "Label":{
            "Position":[137,100],
             "Width":72,
             "Height":20,
             "Text":"Hi Steve",
             "FontSize":18,
             "Color":[0,0,0,1]
        },
        "Label":{
            "Position":[43,342],
             "Width":54,
             "Height":20,
             "Text":"Login:",
             "FontSize":18,
             "Color":[0,0,0,1]
        },
        "Label":{
            "Position":[115,234],
             "Width":54,
             "Height":20,
             "Text":"Button",
             "FontSize":18,
             "Color":[0,0,0,1]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I would like the output to be:

```
{
    "View_1":{
        "Image_1":{
            "BackgroundImage":"Image.png",
             "Position":[0,0],
             "Width":320,
             "Height":480
        },
        "Button_1":{
            "BackgroundImage":"ButtonTop.png",
             "Position":[61,83],
             "Width":217,
             "Height":58
        },
        "Button_2":{
            "BackgroundImage":"ButtonBottom.png",
             "Position":[61,214],
             "Width":205,
             "Height":73
        },
        "TextField_1":{
            "BackgroundImage":"TextFieldLogin.png",
             "Position":[102,336],
             "Width":189,
             "Height":31
        },
        "Label_1":{
            "Position":[137,100],
             "Width":72,
             "Height":20,
             "Text":"Hi Steve",
             "FontSize":18,
             "Color":[0,0,0,1]
        },
        "Label_2":{
            "Position":[43,342],
             "Width":54,
             "Height":20,
             "Text":"Login:",
             "FontSize":18,
             "Color":[0,0,0,1]
        },
        "Label_3":{
            "Position":[115,234],
             "Width":54,
             "Height":20,
             "Text":"Button",
             "FontSize":18,
             "Color":[0,0,0,1]
        }
    }
}
```

How could I use javascript .replace() to add the numbering on demand, and then remove the numbering on demand?

Comment: Are you able to modify the input string? Can't you just pass a collection of buttons, labels and image? like `{ 'view': { 'buttons':[{"Position":[123:423]}, {"Position":[25:335]}], 'images': [...] }}`

Comment: negative. That has been discussed, but the ordering of the object is extremely important and must be delivered the way I specified above. Adding unique incrementing numbers is the best way that I can think of. It must also be predictable numbering so that I can target the desired property. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You probably know this, but you shouldn't be passed such a JSON string in the first place. It can't be parsed without losing information, which is why you will need to resort to ugly string manipulations.

Comment: I've got to say, pretty much anything you do here is going to be a dirty hack. Why is it impossible to say something like `View : { children : [ { type : "Button", data : { /* position : ... */ } }, { type : "Image", data : { /* ... */ } } ] }` -- now everything can be in order, you have no duplicate names, and looping through the results is as simple as looping through, constructing an element/object of `node.type`, and then setting all of the `node.data` properties (or passing them to the constructor for `node.type`), and then appending to the view in-order. If you own the JSON, it's easier.

Comment: To wit, you're not even being passed valid JSON... So somebody/s dropped one or various balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this? I agree with the other voices here recommending that whoever is supplying this "JSON" be responsible for providing valid syntax, but barring that possibility this might get you started:

```
function formatJSON(input) {
  return input.replace(/"([^"]+?)":{(.+)}/g, function(string, key, value) {
    var dict = {};
    return '"' + key + '":{' + value.replace(/"([^"]+?)":{(.+?)}/g, function(string, key, value) {
      dict[key] = dict[key] == undefined ? 1 : ++dict[key];
      return '"' + key + '_' + dict[key] + '":{' + formatJSON(value) + '}';
    }) + '}';
  });
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WYkAT/

Note that this will fail to rename all keys on a more complex, deeper JSON string. It could be easily modified to be more recursive and less specific to your particular situation, but would likely result in some performance degradation. If you need a fully fledged solution, I'd look to modifying an existing JSON.parse polyfill. Here are two (JSON2 and JSON3):

1. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
2. https://github.com/bestiejs/json3

Comment: This does exactly what I am looking for, but how would I add the same number incrementing to the top tier "View":{?

Comment: Well, in this case (and in the case of all properly formatted JSON) there's only one top-tier object. So, after the 2nd "return" just make it `return '"' + key + '"_1:{'` ...

Comment: This worked. I had to use another regex to remove spaces and line breaks, but it worked. thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RegEx expression and pass a function in to the `replace()` method to generate the new name. Assuming `json` contains the string;

```
var i = 0;
json.replace(/\"Button\"/g, function(match) { return '"Button_' + i++ + '"'; });
```

For more info see the part *Find & replace with style…* in this article [Regular Expressions in JavaScript, part 2](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regular-expressions-in-javascript-part-2/).

**EDIT:**

To get an array of the possible object names use this;

```
var names = json.match(/\"(\w*)\"\s?:\s?{/g)
```

You can then loop through the array to do all the replacements;

```
for(n = 0; n < names.length; n++) {
   var i = 0;
   var name = names[n].replace(/\s?:\s?{/g,'');
   var re = new RegExp(name,'g');
   json = json.replace(re, function(match) { return '"' + name.replace(/"/g,'') + '_' + i++ + '"'; });
}
```

You have to create the RegEx object this time to insert the variable.

Comment: This could work, but I believe it would require me to have a .replace() for every possible property, which this is just a sample. We have dozens of types. Is it possible to do soe similar to your but just add the number to the word immedietely before the `:{` within the ""?

Comment: @Rob You would need some way to extract what are the object names versus just the property values i.e replace "Button" but not "Position". You could use an array to store the possible names to replace and then loop through them. You could even use a RegEx to pull out the matching names see my edit.

Comment: @Rob, sorry the name RegExp had extra quotes and the json string was being overwritten in each loop rather than retaining the changes. I've fixed that now. Hope this does what you want.